# Problem selecting multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using a checkbox that has the name as "selectedids[]" and I am trying to select all checkboxes with the JavaScript. The code is not working. When I change the name of the checkbox to "selectedids" it works, but I can't do so because I need all the ids that are selected on the POSTED page.

The checkbox is as follows:

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedids[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="checkbox" />
........
........
}
```

And the Java-script function is as follows:

```
function SetAllCheckBoxes(CheckValue)
{
    var CheckValue=true;
    if(!document.forms['main'])
        return;
    var objCheckBoxes = document.forms['main'].elements['selectedids[]'];
    if(!objCheckBoxes)
        return;
    var countCheckBoxes = objCheckBoxes.length;
    if(!countCheckBoxes)
        objCheckBoxes.checked = CheckValue;
    else
        // set the check value for all check boxes
        for(var i = 0; i < countCheckBoxes; i++)
            objCheckBoxes[i].checked = CheckValue;
}
```

Please help me......

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the option to use jQuery?  If so, then you could do something like:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('checked',true);
});
```

It also *might* work to try:

```
$(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

Or, if you just want to make sure all the boxes are checked only when the page first loads you could have your php that creates the checkboxes include "CHECKED". i.e.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='selectedids[]' value='value' CHECKED>
```

**Updated to use :checkbox per comment**

Comment: you probably mean `$(':checkbox')`, notice the colon

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just select them by id?
e.g.

```
var a=0;
while(document.getElementById('mycheckbox_'+a))document.getElementById('mycheckbox_'+a).checked=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would use the class of the checkboxes to identify them, with a bit of jQuery.
This would work:

```
$('input.checkbox').each(function(){$(this).attr('checked',true);   });
```

It would set all checkboxes with class "checkbox" as true.

---

Beaten to it!